# How to show another php files other than Drupal8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

Thank you for looking at my question.

I have a website created by Drupal8.
And I want to put contact form made in PHP instead of Drupal webform.

I placed the files like this.

```
DocumentRoot/
|- core/
|- sites/
|- themes/
etc.
|- myform/
     |- index.php
```

And I sat permissions to "myform" and "index.php" like this,

```
chmod 775 DocumentRoot/myform
chmod 664 DocumentRoot/myform/index.php
```

But It returns 403 Error when I accessed "hxxps://example.com/myform/".

What should I do? If you have any ideas, please tell me how to read php files other than Drupal.

Comment: _“When I accessed "hxxps://example.com/form/"”_ - you mean, `hxxps://example.com/myform/`?

Comment: That's right. Thank you for your advice. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal wants you to create new routes 'The Drupal Way' - in your case you could create a custom module. This contains your `MyForm.php` that extends `Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase`. Then you add a routing file to tell drupal about your new path.

This tutorial is a couple years old, but should lead you in the right direction: http://karimboudjema.com/en/drupal/20181013/create-custom-form-form-api-drupal-8

Comment: Thank you for giving me good information. I will try it as a reference.

By the way, leave if it's contact form aside, can't I read the PHP files under self made directories like "myform"? 
You may feel it strange, but if you know it, please let me know.

Comment: You could probably modify the .htaccess and allow to load the PHP directly in the browser, but then you're missing out on all the good Drupal stuff : )